# How do you describe a CDF in terms of another CDF?

Tags: probability, statistics

This is homework, but I'm more interested in understanding the problem than the solution, so answering with a different example is totally fine. The problem has multiple parts, but I'm only stuck on this.

We have a CDF $F_x(x)$ for a continuous random variable, $X$. The CDF was not given. But we want to express the CDF $F_y(y)$ in terms of $F_x(x)$. We define $Y = 1 - 2X$.

How do we find this? I know that $F_x(-\infty)=0$ and $F_x(\infty)=1$ for a CDF. I've been scouring the book and the internet but I can't find where this is explained.

At first, I was thinking you could do $F_y(y)=1-2F_x(x)$ but then $F_x(-\infty)=1$ and $F_x(\infty)=-1$ right? Which isn't possible for a CDF. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** We have 
$$F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr(1-2X\le y)=\Pr\left(X\ge \frac{1+y}{2}\right).$$